# how can store Sensitive data in Session in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor WebAssembly and I want to store user data in the session. I have used localStorage and sessionStorage but users may view or temper the data stored in localStorage and sessionStorage which is not the best way to store sensitive data. Tell me how can resolve this issue and how can store sensitive data in session using Blazor WebAssembly

Comment: [Where does it come from, and where does it go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD5Cu3R3030)? You can't just store something in the browser and hope the user doesn't touch it. Does the user enter it, do you obtain it from a third party, can you give us _some_ more context? You could probably store it server-side, but not if the user provides it, because again, how will you know you can trust the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blazor there are 3 hosting models Blazor Server, Blazor WASM, and Blazor Hybrid. Blazor Server runs on the server which means that sensitive data are on the server and safely managed (Until you expose them somehow). And this might help you in some way if you don't need a full-fledged SPA and API. And Blazor Hybrid is a hosting model that runs on the web and on native technologies like .NET MAUI, WPF, and Windows Forms.

Blazor WASM is a single-page application framework used to build interactive client-side UI. This means that it runs and executes on the client. Because of this, you can't store sensitive data in any way with the client. These sensitive data include and are not limited to:

1. Database connection strings
2. User data like passwords
3. secrets to access any protected APIs

On the other hand, there are use cases where you can store data either in the local storage or session storage like:

1. E-commerce websites like saving cart products for unauthenticated users
2. Website state like theme, colors, etc

So that is said, in case you have to access/read sensitive data for a user/client is that you build an API that is being consumed by the user. Of course, you should authenticate and authorize the client in order to access the API.

Read More in-depth articles about what I wrote:

Read more about authentication and authorization with Azure Active Directory (AAD): [Secure a hosted ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly app with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Read more about Blazor server: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server)

Read more about Blazor Hybrid: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-hybrid)

Read More about Blazor State Management [ASP.NET Core Blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly)

Comment: This is good information, but not to the point enough, because OP's question is not clear enough.

Comment: You are totally right. I just answered the point of storing sensitive data only.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful inof  @Mohammed Alwedaei