# Session Storage Blazor WebAssembly Net7.0

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

How can I utilise session storage easily throughout a blazor web assembly app so that I can show/hide razor content based on the session storage cookie?

Comment: https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/session-storage-705060

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server

Comment: https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727463/how-can-store-sensitive-data-in-session-in-blazor-webassembly

Comment: In short - yes. It is well-documented, and hopefully one or more of those links helps you

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `ProtectedSessionStorage` in blazor,follow this part of [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#save-and-load-data-within-a-component).

Notice it's not available during prerendering

Comment: Is this not for server applications and not webassembly?